# BroadcastReceiver not receiving after rerunning app or rebooting

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-widget

I have an AppWidget where I am registering a BroadcastReceiver in my OnEnabled() method:

```
public void onEnabled(Context context){
    //Create the intent
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(context, LightRowWidget.class);
    sendIntent.setAction(ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

    // Get the ids
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] ids = manager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, LightRowWidget.class));

    // set the broadcastReceiver
    NetworkReceiver mReceiver = new NetworkReceiver(sendIntent, ids);
    // Register it
    // Register the broadcast for connectivity change, which also receives disabling of a
    // widget.(if widget is disabled, broadcast will be unregistered).
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    // add a filter
    intentFilter.addAction(widgetDisabled);
    intentFilter.addAction(connectivityChange);
    intentFilter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    context.getApplicationContext()
            .registerReceiver(mReceiver,intentFilter);
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Is OnEnabled() function is called by a service?

Comment: are you registering your receiver in `onResume()` method or not ?

Comment: There is no onResume() in an AppWidgetProvider in Android, since an AppWidgetProvider extends the BroadcastReceiver class

Comment: OnEnabled() function is called the the first widget is created. When I run the app again, the widget is already on the homescreen, but i don't understand why it would be unregistered.